# Unix cannot delete file with Bash script

Tags: bash

I cannot delete file from bash file, if I type command directly in command line then is OK, otherwise if I try to run command inside bash file it's look like is OK but file is never deleted.

So, command: `rm -f /folder/folder/folder/file_name`

If I run this in bash file let say `delete.sh`:

```
!/bin/sh
echo ============== DELETING START ==============
rm -f /folder/folder/folder/file_name
echo ============== DELETING END  ================
echo DELETING RESULT:: Success
status=$?
echo Script execution status:: $status
```

File was never deleted like it's not possible to delete file from bash file.
Any tips.

Comment: First of all, you are missing `#` in the first line; should be `#!/bin/sh`. If that is just a copy-paste problem... try to remove `-f` option, as it can sometimes hide errors. Also, please confirm that you are the one running the script, and not e.g. `cron` or `httpd`.

Comment: `$?` contains exit status of last executed command, here from `echo`.